# Почему Meanio не загружает Livereloadjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

На cloud9 развернул nodejs проект, установил mean.io. Все отлично, проект запускает, тесты выполняются успешно, но сам сайт грузит очень долго, а после загрузки страницы выдает такую ошибку в консоли браузера:
GET https://barstaxi-sbeatport.c9users.io:35729/livereload.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

В документации вот что пишут 
https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js#using-livereloadjs
Говорят что нужно подключить этот файл

что за файл, где он подключается не могу понять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c9 поддерживает несколько [портов](https://docs.c9.io/docs/multiple-ports), этот порт нужно указать в подключаемом файле foot.html и передать порт в конфиг файле.

Чтобы не менять ядро системы необходимо наследовать foot.html, после этого перезаписать.

Тогда сайт загружается быстро, livereloadjs будет грузится.